# Entity Frame Work Code First Not Working

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am unable to successfully create the database from the code, below is my code.

```
public class ProductDatabaseInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ProductContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(ProductContext context)
    {
        GetCategories().ForEach(c => context.Categories.Add(c));
        GetProducts().ForEach(p => context.Products.Add(p));
    }

    private static List<Category> GetCategories()
    {
        var categories = new List<Category> {
            new Category
            {
                CategoryID = 1,
                CategoryName = "Cars"
            }
        };

        return categories;
    }

    private static List<Product> GetProducts()
    {
        var products = new List<Product> {
            new Product
            {
                ProductID = 1,
                ProductName = "Convertible Car",
                Description = "This convertible car is fast!", 
                ImagePath = "carconvert.png",
                UnitPrice = 22.50,
                CategoryID = 1
            }
        };

        return products;
    }
}
```

Product Context Class

```
public class ProductContext : DbContext
{
    public ProductContext()
        : base("WingtipToys")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CartItem> ShoppingCartItems { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Global.asax on Start event

```
// Initialize the product database.
Database.SetInitializer(new ProductDatabaseInitializer());
```

when i run the application the database is not created.

**Web.Config**

```
<add name="WingtipToys" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLOCALDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\wingtiptoys.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Can you show your `ProductContext` also?

Comment: yes please check

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `context.SaveChanges();` in your seed.

Comment: protected override void Seed(ProductContext context)
        {
            GetCategories().ForEach(c => context.Categories.Add(c));
            GetProducts().ForEach(p => context.Products.Add(p));
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

Answer (score 0):

i have found solution for the above problem  in `Global.asax`

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
    {
        void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Code that runs on application startup
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            // Initialize the product database.
            Database.SetInitializer(new ProductDatabaseInitializer());

            using (var context = new ProductContext())
            {
                context.Database.Initialize(force: true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any code for it, so I will ask, but do you act upon anything inside:

`protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {}`

Also, how are you trying to generate your DB, do you use 'migrations' ?

Without forgetting that it is needed for you to apply changes to your context with `context.SaveChanges();`